# Invariant Violation using react-native-svg

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-svg

I have the following error when I try to use **react-native-svg**:

[image: error-screenshot]

I use react-native-svg like this in my code:
[image: code-screenshot]

and I call the component like this

```
import BarChart from './BarChart'

// ...
```

I am using react-native-svg : 9.13.3 and expo : 36
I installed react-native-svg with expo install react-native-svg and I already try to relaunch with reset cache.....
save me please lol
have a nice day !

Comment: Have you solved this? I do have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most probably coming from how you import your `Svg`.

From the documentation I found if you are using **Expo**, then you need to import as:

```
/* Use this if you are using Expo */

import * as Svg from 'react-native-svg';
const { Circle, Rect } = Svg;
```

Instead of your example:

```
import Svg, { Circle, Rect } from 'react-native-svg';
```

See under [`Usage`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#usage) section.